# Properties of the positive definite Hessian matrix of a convex function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, conic-sections, nonlinear-optimization

I'm reading about nonlinear programming and I'm having trouble understanding the cool properties that a positive definite Hessian matrix $Q$ of $n$-dimensional function $f: \mathbf{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ has. I have added a picture from my nonlinear programming book and I included my questions into it:

[image]

I have also a fourth question, if someone wants to answer it as well:

Why is the path of steepest descent method zig-zag orthogonal? Thank you for any help! Please let me know if my question is unclear.

Comment: The answers can be quiiiiite long, but here is an idea. Try to think about the bivariate normal distribution and what appears in the exponent of the exponential: the exponent is the squared Mahalanobis distance between a point $x\in \mathbb R^2$ and the mean point $\bar x$, with the inverse of the covariance matrix $\Sigma^{-1}$ appearing in between. The loci of points with constant squared Mahalanobis distance from $\bar x$ are ellipsoids: this is the crucial passage. Are you ok with this? (to be continued)

Comment: +1 Thank you @Avitus for your help =) I think I'm ok with that :) I  have a black box understanding of the idea, but if I would need to explain this to someone else, I perhaps couldn't do it. The connection between ellipsoid, Hessian, eigenvectors, positive definiteness etc. has been bugging me a long time and still I don't feel comfortable with the idea :P I haven't been able yet to find a tutorial, which would glue all the geometry, linear algebra, etc. together :/ If I could just get all the pieces fit together it would help me with a lot of situations :)

Comment: ok, I will write an answer :)

Comment: +1 Damn, you are an answer machine :D What would SE do without you ;D

Comment: a safer place ahahah :D (joking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symmetric real $n\times n$ matrix $A$ has real eigenvalues and it is diagonalizable, with

$$A=Q\Lambda Q^t, $$

where $Q$ is the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors $q_i$'s of $A$ and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the (real) eigenvalues of $A$. The eigenvectors are orthogonal, and through normalization they can be orthonormalized.
The quadratic form $\langle x, Ax\rangle$ admits the explicit form

$$\langle x, Ax\rangle=\langle x, Q\Lambda Q^t x\rangle =\langle Q^tx, \Lambda Q^t x\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(\langle q_i, x\rangle)^2,$$

as $\Lambda_{i,r}=\lambda_i\delta_{i,r}$ (the last equality above follows from a direct computation: consider the vector $y:=Q^tx$ in the scalar product).

- The case of positive definite symmetric matrices: ellipsoids

Let $A$ be a positive definite real symmetric matrix. This implies, in particular, that its inverse $A^{-1}$ exists. The above considerations hold, as well. For any such matrix $A$,  the locus of points in $\mathbb R^n$s.t.

$$\langle x, Ax\rangle = k,~~k>0 $$

is an ellipsoid (centered at $0$ for simplicity). 
To find the semi-axis of the ellipsoid we use the above diagonalization of $A$, i.e. $A=Q\Lambda Q^t$: geometrically this is equivalent to rotate the ellipsoid until its semi axis lie on the coordinate axis. In the new-i.e. rotated-coordinate system 
$$y= Q^tx $$
the ellipsoid becomes
$$\langle y, \Lambda y\rangle = k,~~k>0 ~~(**)$$

The advantage is that the matrix "representing" the ellipsoid is now diagonal.
We intersect the rotated ellipsoid with the $j$-th coordinate axis in $\mathbb R^n$; this is equivalent to select any $\hat y=(0,\dots,0,y_j,0,\dots,0)\in \mathbb R^n$ and plug it in $(**)$ (think about the $n=2$ case) obtaining

$$\langle \hat y, \Lambda \hat y\rangle = k \Leftrightarrow \lambda_j y_j^2= k \Leftrightarrow y_j=\pm \sqrt\frac{k}{\lambda_j},$$

i.e. the $j$-th eigenvalue $\lambda_j$ of $A$ defines the length of the $j$-th semi axis of the ellipsoid. Note that the eigenvectors  are the coordinate axis in the new coordinate system (up to scaling factors).

- Add on: statistics

As $A$ is positive definite and symmetric, its inverse $A^{-1}$ exists. If you consider the case of multivariate normal distributions, you can use the above considerations with $A^{-1}=\Sigma^{-1}$, where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of the distribution itself. In fact, in the exponent of the exponential in the definition of the distribution the **inverse** of the covariance matrix appears (and the exponent is equal to the squared Mahalanobis distance of the given point from the mean, up to normalization). In the bivariate case you can talk about (and draw explicitly) the contour ellipsoids of the given distribution.

Comment: +1 Excellent!, thank you for your time! Huge thank you =)

Comment: you are welcome sir/ madame! Enjoy the steepest descent, natural gradient and their friends :)

Comment: +1 Thank you sir/madame =D I will try my very best :) I'm sir ;)

Comment: Hi @Avitus one more question if I may :) In your answer you wrote that $y_j=\pm \sqrt{k/\lambda_j}$, but in my book it is stated that the lengths of the semi axes are proportional to $1/\lambda_j$, that is the length is $y_j = c/\lambda_j$? Why the difference? =)

Comment: I believe it is due to the use of $A$ or $A^{-1}$ in the elipsoid. For example, in $n=2$ dimensions, the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is written as $\langle (x,y), A (x,y)\rangle =1$, where the diagonal matrix $A$ has diagonal elements $1/a^2$ and $1/b^2$ (which are also the eigenvalues). So the semi axis have lengths proportional to $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$. But clearly $A=B^{-1}$ and if you use $B$ in the definition you have a factor $1/...$ in the semi axis lengths. It depends on the matrix you are starting with.

Comment: +1 Okay, thank you very much =) So it's partly about selecting the matrix $A$ so that the calculations and expressions clean up to a nice form? =)

Comment: Once the matrix $A$ in the definition of the ellipsoid is clearly defined, the rest just follows.