# Axis aligned and non aligned ellipses and semi definite programming

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections, semidefinite-programming

Let's say I have a equation

$$X_1^T \Omega X_1 =1 $$

$X_1$ is a $2\times 1$ matrix. $\Omega$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix. This defines an ellipse. $\Omega$ is a positive, semi definite, symmetric matrix. I have the following questions:

**1.** Is the ellipse defined by $\Omega$ axis aligned or non aligned or we cannot say?

**2.** If $\Omega$ only contains non zero elements in the diagonal is it definitely axis aligned?

**3.** If $\Omega$ contains non zero elements on and off the diagonal (still being symmetric) is it non-axis aligned?

**4.** If an ellipse is non axis aligned whats the link with semi definite programming?

Comment: Have a look at this answer for some computations: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881461/properties-of-the-positive-definite-hessian-matrix-of-a-convex-function/881517#881517

Comment: Thanks!.Am I right to say                                         1. If omega has only diagonal elements then it's axis aligned. If elements off the diagonal are non zero this its not axis aligned. After reading the link I saw that by applying a rotation(for positive semi definite matrices) it can be written in a way that its axis aligned in a transformed space (where the basis of the space are eigenvectors). If I am right so far I still have one lingering question "4.If an ellipse is non axis aligned whats the link with semi definite programming?"

Comment: btw...the link was really well written.Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the gentle words: nice that you found it useful. Unfortunately, I know nothing about semi-definite programming and the tag has not yet a wiki summary on Math SE; sorry about that.